# How to send notification to app users in android?

Tags: android, database, notifications, push, send

I have an application that contains some user data, name,location and number. I want to send this data to all users of this app as a notification. These data are stored in SQLite database. How can I do this? Can anyone help me to do this with some examples?

Comment: Use GCM https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the concept of Broadcast Receiver,Notification Manager,Alarm Manager and pending intenet for this.
you can get various examples from google very easily regarding this topic.
Fetch your data from your database and put it in the Broadcast Receiver class.

Comment: can you elaborate it by giving an example?